# Unnecessary information about model in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have index method in my controller, there is I have one line:

```
@channels = Channel.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
```

I use gem "Haml-rails" and I have view like this:
**index.html.haml**

```
- provide(:title, "Channels")

.offset1
  = @channels.each do |channel|
    Channel name:
    = channel.name
    %br
    Url:
    %a
      = channel.url
    %br
    = link_to "Change", edit_channel_path(channel)
    |
    = link_to "Delete", channel, method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
    %br
```

And it's works, but in view it output information about model:

```
[#<Channel id: 1, name: "tut.by", url: "http://tut.by/rss/rss.all", created_at: "2013-09-13 11:21:14", updated_at: "2013-09-13 11:21:14", user_id: 17>, #<Channel id: 2, name: "youtube.com", url: "http://youtube.com/rss/rss.all", created_at: "2013-09-13 11:54:50", updated_at: "2013-09-13 11:54:50", user_id: 17>]
```

I don't understand why this is output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
= @channels.each do |channel|
#The equals character is followed by Ruby code. 
#This code is evaluated and the output is inserted into the document.
```

to

```
- @channels.each do |channel| 
#The hyphen character is also followed by Ruby code. 
#This code is evaluated but not inserted into the document.
```

[source](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_)